# Android WallPaper Service

Tags: android, wallpaper

When I used to install on Android 7.1.2 it works fine.
       But on Samsung Android Version 8.1.0 it crashes.
       Then I later change the code as below

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
               intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
               new ComponentName(this,LiveWallPaperService.class));
               startActivity (intent)
```

Calling service using `startActivity (intent)` crashes in 8.1.0.
       So, I used, `startService ( intent )`.
       It starts a Custom Wallpaper service class(`LiveWallPaperService`).
       But it does not call WallpaperService and draw wallpaper as in Android 7.1.2 version

Comment: share logcat please.

Comment: Here is the logcat when run on 7.1.2

Comment: 2019-06-14 13:46:51.860 24243-24243/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:125842099 intent:Intent { act=android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (has extras) }
    
    ------ beginning of system
2019-06-14 13:46:51.935 24243-24243/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper I/Choreographer: Skipped 318 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-06-14 13:46:52.058 24243-24364/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7f7a456c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f7a4ee3c0

Comment: Here is the logcat when run on 8.1.0

Comment: 2019-06-15 10:29:10.624 20511-20511/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper I/Choreographer: Skipped 394 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-06-15 10:29:11.167 20511-20511/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper E/LiveWallPaperService: Draw Wallpaper Called
2019-06-15 10:29:11.666 20511-20511/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper E/LiveWallPaperService: draw Called
2019-06-15 10:29:11.667 20511-20511/com.surfaceapp.borderlightwallpaper I/Choreographer: Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.